# Kohana 3.2 - Session database

Tags: session, kohana

i use kohana 3.2 and i have problem with session database, everytime i use Session::Instance() in my site i get a new database record for it. also the sessions doesn't work at all  even i set a new value to it

in login page

```
public function action_index()
{
    if ( Session::instance()->get('logged'))
        $this->request->redirect('home');


    $this->response->body(View::factory('pages/login'));

}
```

in auth function

```
public function action_authenticate()
{
    $username = $this->request->post('username');
    $password = $this->request->post('password');

    $user = ORM::factory('user');
    $data = $user->user_login($username, $password);

    if ( $data == $username){


         Session::instance()->set('logged', true);

         $this->request->redirect('home');

    }
    else
    {
        echo "incorrect username or password";
    }
```

and in Home page i just redirect back to login if logged isn't set

```
 function action_index(){

    if (  ! Session::instance()->get('logged'))
        $this->request->redirect('login');


   $this->template->header = View::factory('pages/header')->render();
   $this->template->footer = view::factory('pages/footer')->render();
   $data['sidebar'] = View::factory('pages/sidebar')->render();
   $this->template->content = View::factory('pages/home',$data);

}
```

in bootstrap.php i added  Session::$default = 'database'; so it uses database by default.
if i remove database mode it works just fine and if its there i get all time 3 database records since i call Session::instance  3 times ?

i am new to kohana. but not new to php.

thanks for help

Comment: check your cookies. Does the session cookie get set? Does the session_id in the cookie is different with every request?

Answer (score 0):

set Cookie::$salt in bootstrap.php. Add this line in your bootstrap.php.

```
Cookie::$salt = 'YourSecretCookieSalt';
```